# custom hook not updating components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wrote a simple custom hook to control a countdown timer. In it, I have a state variable for the remaining seconds. Subtraction from this variable is triggered on a button click, and should subtract 1000 ms per second of interval. The Display component is responsible for showing the changed `seconds` variable

The functions get triggered appropriately, aka the subtraction is working internally, however, the change in seconds is not propagated to all components and the display component does not change. See [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-wu-j6ti3).

I was under the impression that the change in state (seconds) should also re-render its dependent recipients since the seconds variable is used there.

How do I get the Display component to track the change in value?

Answer (score 0):

Your custom hook is scoped to the component it which it's called. Any `useState` call will store information locally and it wouldn't be shared at all.

You must use Context API to lift this state up the tree and then you can use `useContext` hook to gain access to it in lower components. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext